# How do I use lists in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How do I represent invoices into an MySQL table structure?

The invoice table has the following fields:

```
id
customer_id
services
tax
total_price
date
...
```

Now the services can contain one or more articles and, what makes it complicated, various prices. The actual price of a service is negotiated, there are seldom fixed prices because each customer has individual requirements. These items have to be listed on the invoice and the prices of each have to be listed and summarized + tax.

What is the best practice for this purpose? I want to make it normalized if possible, something more sophisticated than just saving an (serialized) array of service => price into the service field, if this is possible at all. Do I use a second table for each service + price and hold a list of IDs with foreign keys?

Comment: Second table for each Service + Price and a reference on that table to the invoice table.

Comment: I would use serialize in backend

Comment: or just one additional table with service and price. If the price is negotiated each time, it might not be efficient to have two additional tables. Probably not 3NF however.

Comment: Would this make sense at all, if the service and the price are not reoccurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should follow Has And Belongs To Many relationship. Fr that you  use two more tables for this one is `'services'` and other is `'invoice_services'`

`'services'` table contain service info and its price etc.
`'invoice_services'` table will be the join table for `'invoice'` and `'services'` tables. `'invoice_services'` table will contain `'service_id'` and `'invoice_id'`.

Then you can remove the column `'services'` from `'invoice'` table.

If you want to maintain negotiable price for each service, then you can add one more field `'custom_price'` in `'invoice_services'` table.

Then using joins you can fetch the relative data of any invoice.

Hope this may help :)